# Como saber el numero de la fila de una de html que he seleccionado

Tags: javascript, html5

Buen día, tengo un codigo que genera una tabla segun los meses que selecciono con un determinado vector que puede ser cualquier número, entonces al darle en el botón guardar, se genera una tabla con la funcion de javascript, osea guardo los meses en un array y genero una tabla con los objetos del array. Pero quiero que tengan un boton que al darle click se elimine esa fila y tambien se elimine el array, por eso quería saber si existe una funcion que al darle click a la fila, me de el número para poder borrarlo del array.

Espero que me entiendan lo que les quiero decir, gracias.

aqui les pongo el codigo que tengo.

```js
const mes_especial = [];
const vector_mensual = [];
function guardar_mes_especial() {
 var inputmes = document.getElementById('mesEspecial');
 var ms = inputmes.options[inputmes.selectedIndex].text;
 var vs = document.getElementById('vectorMensual').value;
 if (ms != 'Elige un mes' && vs != 1) {
  mes_especial.push(ms);
  vector_mensual.push(vs);
 }
 document.querySelector('#mesespecial').innerHTML = generarTablaMesesEspeciales(mes_especial, vector_mensual);
 document.ready = document.getElementById('mesEspecial').value = '13';
 document.ready = document.getElementById('vectorMensual').value = '1';
}
function generarTablaMesesEspeciales(mes_especial, vector_mensual) {
 var tabla1 =
  "<table id='tablita1' class='table'> <thead class='thead-light'> <tr><th scope='col'>Mes</th><th scope='col'>Vector mensual</th></tr></thead>";
 tabla1 += '<tbody>';
 for (var i = 0; i < mes_especial.length; i++) {
  tabla1 += '<tr><td>' + mes_especial[i] + '</td><td>' + vector_mensual[i] + '</td></tr>';
 }
 tabla1 += '</tbody>';
 tabla1 += '</table>';
 return tabla1;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Fechas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1 class="display-1 text-center bg-light text-dark">Cuotas</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                          
                        
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="mesEspecial">Meses especiales</label>
                          <select name="mesEspecial" id="mesEspecial" class="form-control">
                          <option value="13">Elige un mes</option>
                          <option value='0'>Enero</option>
                          <option value='1'>Febrero</option>
                          <option value='2'>Marzo</option>
                          <option value='3'>Abril</option>
                          <option value="4">Mayo</option>
                          <option value="5">Junio</option>
                          <option value="6">Julio</option>
                          <option value="7">Agosto</option>
                          <option value="8">Septiembre</option>
                          <option value="9">Octubre</option>
                          <option value="10">Noviembre</option>
                          <option value="11">Diciembre</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="vectorMensual">Vector del mes</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="vectorMensual" id="vectorMensual" placeholder="Introduce el vector" value="1" min="0" max="10" step="0.25" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                            <label for="guardar"> </label>
                            <br>
                            <button name="guardar" class="btn btn-light" id="guardar" onclick="guardar_mes_especial()">Guardar</button>
                          </div>
                         
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group text-center">
                          <div id="mesespecial"></div>
                       </div>
                        
                        
                
                
                
              </div>

        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

aca te dejo una posible solucion echa en jQuery :

pasando como parametro el elemente que fue presionado `onclick="remove(this)"` adentro de la funcion `remove()` agarramos el indice del elemento padre con `el.closest("tr").index()` y sucesivamente borramos el valor al interno del array gracias a la funcion `splice` que le decimos que elimine el valor que se encuentra en la posición del indice y que borre 1 solo elemento y quedaria asi : `array.splice(indice, 1)`

ejemplo funcionante :

```js
var table = $(".table");

var array = [ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6];


for (let i = 0 ; i < array.length ; i++){
  table.append("<tr><td>"+array[i]+"</td><td><button type='button' onclick='remove(this)'> X </button></td></tr>")
}

function remove(el){
var index = $(el).closest("tr").index()
  array.splice(index, 1);
  console.log(array)
  $(el).closest("tr").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table">

</table>
```

espero que te sea de ayuda

Comment: Me funciono de maravilla, la agregue un icono de tacho de basura al boton y copie la funcione remove() y me funciono perfectamente. Entonces con la funcion closest se puede obtener el indice de la tabla?

Comment: @DiegoChavez no, con `closest` lo unico que se hace es buscar el elemente mas cercano, en este caso se busca el `<tr>` que vendria a ser el elemento padre del elemento padre.., con `.index()` se toma el indice del elemento. pero visto que cada elemento del array corresponde al `tr` y no al `boton`. espero que resuelva tus dudas

Answer (score 1):

Te dejo una función en `Javascript` como lo solicitas:

```js
const mes_especial = [];
const vector_mensual = [];
function guardar_mes_especial() {
 var inputmes = document.getElementById('mesEspecial');
 var ms = inputmes.options[inputmes.selectedIndex].text;
 var vs = document.getElementById('vectorMensual').value;
 if (ms != 'Elige un mes' && vs != 1) {
  mes_especial.push(ms);
  vector_mensual.push(vs);
 }
 document.querySelector('#mesespecial').innerHTML = generarTablaMesesEspeciales(mes_especial, vector_mensual);
 document.ready = document.getElementById('mesEspecial').value = '13';
 document.ready = document.getElementById('vectorMensual').value = '1';
}
function generarTablaMesesEspeciales(mes_especial, vector_mensual) {
 var tabla1 =
  "<table id='tablita1' class='table'> <thead class='thead-light'> <tr><th scope='col'>Mes</th><th scope='col'>Vector mensual</th></tr></thead>";
 tabla1 += '<tbody>';
 for (var i = 0; i < mes_especial.length; i++) {
  tabla1 += '<tr><td>' + mes_especial[i] + '</td><td>' + vector_mensual[i] + '</td><td><button onclick="deleteRow()"> Eliminar </button></td></tr>';
 }
 tabla1 += '</tbody>';
 tabla1 += '</table>';
 return tabla1;
}

function deleteRow() {

      var td = event.target.parentNode; 
      var tr = td.parentNode;
      var index = Array.from(tr.parentNode.children).indexOf(tr);
      tr.parentNode.removeChild(tr);
      
      mes_especial.splice(index,1);
      vector_mensual.splice(index,1);
      
      //console.log(mes_especial);
      //console.log(vector_mensual);
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <title>Fechas</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css"
        integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <script src="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/js/gijgo.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/gijgo@1.9.11/css/gijgo.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
    <script src="main.js"></script>
</head>

<body>

    <header>
        <h1 class="display-1 text-center bg-light text-dark">Cuotas</h1>
    </header>

    <main>
        <div class="container">
            <div class="row">             
                          
                        
                      <div class="form-row">
                        <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                          <label for="mesEspecial">Meses especiales</label>
                          <select name="mesEspecial" id="mesEspecial" class="form-control">
                          <option value="13">Elige un mes</option>
                          <option value='0'>Enero</option>
                          <option value='1'>Febrero</option>
                          <option value='2'>Marzo</option>
                          <option value='3'>Abril</option>
                          <option value="4">Mayo</option>
                          <option value="5">Junio</option>
                          <option value="6">Julio</option>
                          <option value="7">Agosto</option>
                          <option value="8">Septiembre</option>
                          <option value="9">Octubre</option>
                          <option value="10">Noviembre</option>
                          <option value="11">Diciembre</option>
                          </select>
                        </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4">
                            <label for="vectorMensual">Vector del mes</label>
                            <input class="form-control" type="number" name="vectorMensual" id="vectorMensual" placeholder="Introduce el vector" value="1" min="0" max="10" step="0.25" required>
                          </div>
                          <div class="form-group col-md-4" >
                            <label for="guardar"> </label>
                            <br>
                            <button name="guardar" class="btn btn-light" id="guardar" onclick="guardar_mes_especial()">Guardar</button>
                          </div>
                         
                        
                      </div>
                      <div class="form-group text-center">
                          <div id="mesespecial"></div>
                       </div>
                        
                        
                
                
                
              </div>

        </div>
    </main>

</body>

</html>
```

Lo que realicé fue crear un nuevo `td` que contenga un `button`, a dicho `button` le agregué el evento `onclick`. La función `onclick` se encarga de remover el `row` actual, obtiene el `índice` del `row` y lo elimina de los `arrays` con la función `splice`.

Referencias:
https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/indexOf

https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Referencia/Objetos_globales/Array/from

Espero te sirva. Saludos.

Comment: Me podrias explicar como funciona la parte de agarrar el index??

Comment: Estoy utilizando el "Array.from()", que crea una nueva instancia de Array a partir de un objeto iterable, donde le paso el "children" del nodo padre y utilizando el "indexOf" obtengo el índice. Te dejaré unos links en la respuesta que te pueden servir.